# How to make a python class take on a different class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I am making a virtual assistant in Python. I have a class for a prompt, a currently empty class for processing the request, and will have a class for displaying the result.

Here is my code:

```py
#Pysistant
#Google Assistant clone(ish) built with Python and Tkinter

import tkinter as tk

class Prompt:
    def __init__ (self, typ, message):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.message = message
        self.typ = typ.lower()

        if typ == "one line":
            self.text = tk.Label(self.window, text=self.message)
            self.frame = tk.Frame(self.window)
            self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
            self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Done", command=lambda: self.command_wrapper(self.entry.get().lower()))
            self.text.pack()
            self.entry.pack()
            self.button.pack()
            self.frame.pack()


    def command_wrapper(self, query):
        if "math" or "calc" in query:
           func = "math"
           params = query[5:]
        self = Command(func, params)

    def quit(self):
       self.window.destroy()


class Command:
    def __init__(self, func, params):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.func = func
        self.params = params
        self.text = tk.Label(self.window, text="Processing your request")
        self.text.pack()
        self.quit()

    ###TODO: Create subclasses for different functions


instance = Prompt('one line', "What would you like to accomplish today?")
```

I expect instance to refer to a `Command` object after calling `command_wrapper()`, but it refers to a `Prompt` object. Calling `instance.quit()` just destroys the prompt window.

Comment: Assigning to `self` doesn't modify the original object; it just makes the local variable `self` refer to a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to a `Prompt` instance `self` is not replaced with such an assignment `self = Command(func, params)` (within `command_wrapper` method), being just a local variable i that context.

Your phrase *"I expect instance to refer to a `Command` object "* points to the intention of using ***Delegation***.
Define an additional field for the delegate, say `self._command = None` (within `Prompt` constructor).
Modify `command_wrapper` to set a delegate `self._command = Command(func, params)`.
Change `quit` method to destroy the internal *command* window:

```
def quit(self):
   self._command.window.destroy()
```

But, to eventually destroy the initial *prompt* instance window you'd have to call it directly: `prompt_instance.window.destroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand the question correctly - is this what you are looking for?

```
    def command_wrapper(self, query):
        if "math" or "calc" in query:
            func = "math"
            params = query[5:]
        return Command(func, params)
```

Comment: `instance` still refers to a `Prompt` object.